# Один обработчик ajax запросов

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, mvc

Или иными словами ajax, php, mvc.
Хочется сделать один обработчик (Controller) ajax запросов. Ajax естественно по средствам jquery

Почему? Потому что не хочется плодить кучу файлов обработчиков, в общем пожалуйста если уже есть мануал, статья, ответ на подобный вопрос, подведите меня к истине поближе, интересно как это всё реализовать, были свои задумки как, но хочется и другие посмотреть варианты.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: как-нить более подробно объясните что вы хотите, в mvc существуют контроллеры, и их обычно много, вы можете передавать данные вместо html в виде json, в случае ajax запроса, погуглите "isAjax php"

Comment: В общем затея такова, может яснее станет
url:'/ajax',
data: {functionname: runfunction, params: param}

ajax контроллер, то есть класс который принимает functionname это в будущем сущность класса которая запустится и отработает, с остальными данными (параметрами) и как их грамотно затолкать в функцию (сущность) пока не знаю

Comment: Добавьте в объект data параметры controller, action, на сервере парсите, и вызываете нужный экшн из нужного класса. Не?

Можно сделать еще по другому, вместо параметров controller, и action писать route: "/my/some/route", и на серверсайде парсить его.

Comment: т.е. вы хотите сделать сверхтолстый контроллер вместо того, чтобы прозрачно реализовать json api ?

Comment: я вам могу сказать больше - грамотно реализовав MVC - в частности отдавая VIEW только те данные, что могут быть отправлены в сеть, вы можете сделать отправку ответов на ajax вообще прозрачной для контроллера. i.e.  встроить isAjax в генератор вьюх, выглядит примерно так (php):

    if (isAjax()) {
         header('Content-type: application/json');
         echo json_encode(array($response=>$view_data));
         exit;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю на сколько актуален вопрос, но вот тебе:

1. создаешь контроллер `ajax.php` ( ну или как там у тебя )
2. в контроллере делаешь нужные тебе методы:

   `action_register()
   {
   // тут код метода
   }
   action_login()
   {
   // тут код метода
   }`
3. ну и собственно вызовы **jQuery**

   `$.ajax({
   url: "/ajax/login", // где ajax-контроллер и login - метод
   ...
   })`

   Надеюсь пригодится кому